# PHP Setting hardcoded URL in Global Constant in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Can somebody help me how to avoid hardcoded URL in PHP so when your website have been ready to live, you do not have to look for all your files and edit the all hardcoded url.

In this way, I have created a Global.php 
On my Global.php
I have here this codes.

```
define("main", "http://mainpage.com");
define("registration", "http://mainpage.com/register");
define("login", ""http://mainpage.com/login");
```

on my other sites, I have here a register page. when I wanted to use my global declaration, I'll make it like this.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include'../Global.php'; ?>
    <div class="nav">
                    <div class="navcontainer">
                            <div class="twelve columns">
                                <ul id="menu">
                                      <li><a href="<?php echo $mainpage;?>">
            mainpage</button></a></li>
                                      <li><a href="<?php echo $register;?>"> <button class="navbutton">
            register</button></a></li>
                                      <li><a href="<?php echo $login;?>"><button class="navbutton">
            Log in</button></a></li>
                              </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What i've noticed is that, on my Global.php.. my domain is always repeated.. what I wanted to do is that, i will just define the main page and I will just concatenate the main page to the directory path or file name of a page..

**Global.php**

```
define("main", "http://mainpage.com");

<html>
<body>
<?php include'../Global.php'; ?>
    <div class="nav">
                    <div class="navcontainer">
                            <div class="twelve columns">
                                <ul id="menu">
                                      <li><a href="<?php echo $mainpage";?  >">
            mainpage</button></a></li>
                                      <li><a href="<?php echo $mainpage . "/register";?>"><button class="navbutton">
            register</button></a></li>
                                      <li><a href="<?php echo $main page . "/login";?>"><button class="navbutton">
            Log in</button></a></li>
                              </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But this won'
t work. Can somebody help me how to get the directory file and/or file name of a page and concatenate it with the Global define mainpage?

Comment: Hint: there are 3 kinds of relative URLs

Comment: can I just like here <a href="/main.php">Main</a> <a href="/register.php">register</a> <a href="/login.php">Main</a>  even if it is live?

Comment: the line `define("login", ""http://mainpage.com/login");` contains a syntax error (one too many quote marks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative URLs - you don't have to have the http://example.com, use:

```
<a href="/main.php">Main</a>
```

It will work regardless of the domain.

Edit: If main.php is not directly under http://example.com/, you will need to prefix it with the path to reach it, for example:

```
define('URLBASE', '/path/to');
<a href="<?php echo URLBASE ?>/main.php">Main</a>
```

Whether you choose to use <?= or <?php depends on your PHP version, configuration and personal preference.

Comment: Yes, even if it is live.  This also avoids issues if your code ever has to run on an HTTPS page.

Comment: Is there a way to set all relative URL's to my Global? Or is it advisable to set my relative URLs to my Global?

Comment: If you use define, you reference the value without the $, because it isn't a variable.  You can use 
define('some_constant', 'some_value');
and then
<?php echo some_constant; ?>

Comment: Like here define("register", "/register"); ?

Comment: href="<?php echo register; ?>"

Comment: So there is no problem will arise even if I do that, doesn't matter with relative urls?

Comment: doesn't matter if I do that even if when it live?

Comment: user2182349 do u have gmail? I have few questions to ask

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is only a matter of syntax errors.

First off, you define a `main` **constant** then in the HTML page you try to echo a `mainpage` **variable**. Not the same name, not the same kind…

The following code works like a charm

```
<?php
define("MAINPAGE", "http://mainpage.com");
?>

<html>
  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="navcontainer">
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="<?=MAINPAGE?>"> mainpage</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=MAINPAGE . '/register'?>">
          <button class="navbutton">register</button></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=MAINPAGE . '/login'?>">
          <button class="navbutton">Log in</button></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You'll notice that I'm using short tags `<?=expr?>` where *expr* can be any valid PHP expression, using constants, variables and operators. It is just a shorthand for `<?php echo expr;?>`.

The line with register is equivalent to:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo MAINPAGE . '/register';?>">
```

I'm using a constant, but I could have defined a variable instead:

```
$mainpage = "http://mainpage.com";
```

Then the previous line would be:

```
<li><a href="<?=$mainpage . '/register'?>">
```

Of course, you don't need PHP to do the appending:

```
<li><a href="<?=MAINPAGE?>/register">
```

Answer (score 0):

As already hinted about, the best way for the navigation bar is relative addressing.

```
<li><a href="index.php">
          <button class="navbutton">Home</button></a></li>
<li><a href="registration.php">
          <button class="navbutton">Register</button></a></li>
<li><a href="login.php">
          <button class="navbutton">Log in</button></a></li>
```

I have also found a need for defining the href link with a constant.
In a php configure file:

```
Define('SOCIAL_MEDIA_FACEBOOK' ,'');
```

In an HTML/PHP navigation file:

```
<?php if(SOCIAL_MEDIA_FACEBOOK != '') { ?>
            <a href="<?=SOCIAL_MEDIA_FACEBOOK?>">
                <img src="images/Facebook.png"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

This way when I give the code to a client, there is no Facebook icon, util the client provides a link.